# Java Node swaping

Tags: java, tree, nodes

i wanna swap 2 nodes in java here is my node class

```
public class Node {

    int  freq;
    Node left,right,parent;
    }
```

i wanna swap 2 Nodes in my tree

```
public void swap(Node a, Node b){
Node temp;
temp.freq=a.freq;
temp.parent=a.parent;
temp.left=a.left;
temp.right= a.right;

a.freq=b.freq;
a.left=b.left;
a.right=b.right;
a.parent=b.parent;


b.freq=temp.freq;
b.left=temp.left;
b.right=temp.right;
b.parent=temp.parent;
}
```

but i found that parent of both nodes becomes b.parent 
any hint ????

Comment: Weird, you should be getting a nullpointerexception at `temp.freq=a.freq;` - post a mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your object, Node temp doesn't point to anything besides null. I don't know why your compiler isn't catching this error because using a dot call on a null object will throw a nullpointerexception(e.g. temp.freq; it will have nothing to point to and no internal variables at this point). Make sure that temp points to a new node and try going from there.